Trying to return an array containing random numbers in C++
I am writing a function that generates a random set of numbers. I can print the numbers as separate ints, but I am trying to put the numbers into an array and return the array so I can assign it to another empty array in another function so I can manipulate the array. I looked everywhere, but I couldn't find something that can satisfy my criteria.
My function:
void generateRandomNumbers(int lower, int upper){
    int n = 5;
    int random[n];
    int tempArr = random[n];


    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        random[i] = lower + (rand() % upper);

        cout << random[i] << " ";
    }
}

This function only prints the numbers, but I want it to return it so I can manipulate it. I tried using pointers, but it didn't or I didn't do it right.

It's called std::vector.

You can't return an array directly, prefer std::array or std::vector.

BTW, int random[n] isn't legal in C++ (at the moment) and int tempArr = random[n] would be accessing outside bounds if it were.

If you can use C++11 or newer, please consider std::uniform_int_distribution<int>

Arrays are pass-by-reference in C++. You can define the array outside the function and pass it, instead of returning it. Or you can use vectors.

It's not possible to return an array from a function in C++. It;s also not legal to declare an array whose bounds are not constant. The answer to both these problems is std::vector<int>, that's what your code should be using.

If you want your pointer code fixed (that could work) then you should post that code. If much easier to help fix code if you post the code in the first place.

don't seed the rng everytime you call the function. You should seed it only once

Here's what happens: The array is a local variable. It falls out of scope and is lost when the function exits. Since you can only pass an array by reference, the caller gets a reference (a pointer in this case) to the array that WAS in generateRandomNumbers but is now gone. Trust me, this behaviour made perfect sense in the 1970s when you didn't have the RAM or CPU power to pass arrays around willy-nilly.

Note that lower + (rand() % upper) does not return a random number in the range as you expect.

@lastchance -  There is no "at the moment".  A VLA (like int random[n])  has never been valid in any version of standard C++.   One or two proposals to add it in some form were shot down, with some pretty strong documented arguments - which suggests it never will be.

Use a vector
If you need to pass an array into (or return one from) a function, std::vector is the natural choice. Built-in arrays are a poor choice for at least two reasons:

They are awkward to pass to and from functions.
Their sizes must be specified at compile-time.

Filling a vector is easy. The following function creates vector v as a local variable, runs a loop to fill it with random integers, and then returns it, just like any other variable.
std::vector<int> generateRandomNumbers(
    std::size_t size,
    int const lower,
    int const upper)
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(size);
    while (size--)
        v.push_back(random_integer(lower, upper));
    return v;
}

C++ has a feature called named return value optimization (NRVO) that allows compilers to elide the copy that might otherwise be made when a variable is returned. This makes it very efficient to return a vector from the function that created it.
Later on, when you want to pass a vector into another function, you can pass a reference or a reference to const. This is also very efficient, because the vector itself is not copied.
Function put_vector (below) is a good example. It accepts a reference to a const vector, and outputs the vector to a stream.
void put_vector(
    std::ostream& ost, 
    std::vector<int> const& v)  // lvalue reference to const vector of int
{
    ost.put('[');
    if (!v.empty())
    {
        ost << v[0];
        for (std::size_t i{ 1 }; i < v.size(); ++i)
            ost << ',' << v[i];
    }
    ost.put(']');
}

If you need to pass a vector to a function that modifies its contents, you can pass a (non-const) reference. The reference refers back to the original vector, so any changes made to the vector in the function are actually changing the original vector.
The example below replaces the contents of a vector with new random values.
void load_new_random_values(
    std::vector<int>& v,  // lvalue reference to (non-const) vector of int
    int const lower,
    int const upper)
{
    for (auto& value : v)
        value = random_integer(lower, upper);
}

There is also something called an rvalue reference that is used with move semantics. I am, however, leaving it for another answer.
Problems with random numbers
The OP uses this expression to generate random numbers:
// From the OP:
random[i] = lower + (rand() % upper);

My guess is that the OP wants random numbers on the closed interval [lower, upper]. If so, then the expression above should be changed to:
random[i] = lower + rand() % (upper - lower + 1);

To see how this works, imagine you are rolling dice, so lower = 1, and upper = 6.

The expression (upper - lower + 1) equals 6.

rand() % (upper - lower + 1), therefore, produces a value between 0 and 5. Adding it to lower gives a result between 1 and 6.


Unfortunately, the numbers produced by this expression are not uniformly distributed. Unless RAND_MAX happens to be evenly divisible by 6, there will be a tiny bias in favor of smaller numbers. See below for a way to use std::rand without introducing a bias.
There are many reasons, however, not to use std::rand at all. The next section introduces an alternative.
Random number generation using header <random>
The following function returns a psuedo-random integer on the closed interval [a, b]. Presumably, this is what the OP was trying to code. It seeds the random number generator only once, on the first call to the function.
int random_integer(int const a, int const b)
{
    // Return a pseudo-random integer on the closed interval [a, b].
    static std::mt19937 mt{ std::random_device{}() };
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> random_number;
    using param_type = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::param_type;
    return random_number(mt, param_type{ a, b });
}

Notes
std::mt19937 is a Mersenne Twister random number engine from header <random>.
std::random_device, also from header <random>, is a system-dependent way to generate random, unsigned, 32-bit values. Depending on the system, the values can be either pseudo-random quantities or truly random quantities. It is used above to seed std::mt19937, where the initializer is std::random_device{}(). This instantiates a temporary object of type random_device, and then invokes its "call" operator(), to generate a 32-bit seed.
std::uniform_int_distribution is a random number distribution from header <random>. As its name suggests, it generates uniformly distributed integers using the random bits it gets from a random number engine. When instantiated with type int, e.g. std::uniform_int_distribution<int>, its "call" operator() returns a random integer of type int.
std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::param_type is the type used by std::uniform_int_distribution<int> to specify the range of values from which random integers are drawn. param_type{ a, b } is the closed interval [a, b].
When a "local" variable of a function is declared to be static, it is allocated and initialized only once. This happens on the first invocation of the function. Once allocated, the lifetime of a static variable extends until the end of the program. It holds its value between calls to the function.
In function random_integer (above), static variable mt is seeded only once, during its construction, using std::random_device.
Similarly, static variable random_number is initialized only once, by its default constructor.
The return statement invokes the call operator of object random_number, passing in the random number engine mt and a param_type object that specifies the range.
Using srand and rand
It is possible to code function random_integer using std::rand and std::srand, but the resulting function is not as simple as the version given above.

In order to assure that std::srand is called only once, the version below uses an immediately executed lambda, to initialize a static "local" variable.

In order to guarantee that the returned values are uniformly distributed, the function uses a rejection sampling method adapted from an example at CppReference.

In order to deal with the possibility that RAND_MAX could be as small as 32767, the values of a and b are carefully checked.

In order to emphasize that we'll be using std::rand, the function name has been changed from random_integer to uniform_rand.


#pragma once
// tbx.random.uniform_rand.h
namespace tbx
{
    int uniform_rand(int const a, int const b);
}
// end file: tbx.random.uniform_rand.h

// tbx.random.uniform_rand.cpp
#include <cstdlib>    // rand, srand. RAND_MAX
#include <random>     // random_device
#include <stdexcept>  // runtime_error
#include "tbx.random.uniform_rand.h"

namespace tbx
{
    //==================================================================
    // uniform_rand
    // Return a uniformly distributed, pseudo-random integer on the 
    // closed interval [a, b]. This function uses "rejection sampling."
    // 
    // Precondition: (a <= b) && (b - a <= RAND_MAX)
    // 
    // It is implementation-defined whether `std::rand` is thread-safe. 
    // If `std::rand` is thread-safe, then `tbx::uniform_rand` will 
    // also be thread-safe, but not otherwise.
    //==================================================================
    int uniform_rand(int const a, int const b)
    {
        // Call `srand` on the first pass, and never again, thereafter.
        static thread_local bool const is_seeded{
            []() { std::srand(std::random_device{}()); return true; }()
        };
        if (a > b) {
            throw std::runtime_error("tbx::uniform_rand: a > b");
        }
        static_assert(sizeof(long long) > sizeof(int));
        auto const aa{ static_cast<long long>(a) };
        auto const bb{ static_cast<long long>(b) };
        auto const rand_max{ static_cast<long long>(RAND_MAX) };
        if (bb - aa > rand_max) {
            throw std::runtime_error("tbx::uniform_rand: b - a > RAND_MAX");
        }
        unsigned const desired_range{ 1u + static_cast<unsigned>(bb - aa) };
        unsigned const range_of_rand{ 1u + static_cast<unsigned>(RAND_MAX) };
        unsigned const bucket_size{ range_of_rand / desired_range };
        unsigned n;  // "bucket number"
        do {
            n = static_cast<unsigned>(std::rand()) / bucket_size;
        } while (n >= desired_range);
        return a + static_cast<int>(n);
    }
}
// end file: tbx.random.uniform_rand.cpp

If nothing else, this should convince you that using function rand is not always as straightforward as it seems!
rand is often presented as a quick-and-dirty alternative to using the facilities of header <random>. In this case, it is certainly dirty: the code is less readable than before. Whether it is quicker is up for grabs. In this context, "quicker" usually means quicker for the programmer, which, I can assure you, it was not.
In addition, the values returned by rand are always non-negative numbers, between 0 and RAND_MAX. So, even if RAND_MAX is the same as INT_MAX, the range of generated values is half the size of that available to std::uniform_int_distribution.
All of this is added on top of the fact that the implementation of rand may or may not be of dubious quality on a given compiler, and that RAND_MAX may be as small as 32767.
A complete program
This program demonstrates the functions discussed in the preceding sections. Output from two sample runs is given below.
// main.cpp
#include <cstddef>   // size_t
#include <iostream>  // cout, ostream
#include <random>    // mt19937, random_device, uniform_random_int
#include <vector>    // vector

int random_integer(int const a, int const b)
{
    // Return a pseudo-random integer on the closed interval [a, b].
    static std::mt19937 mt{ std::random_device{}() };
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> random_number;
    using param_type = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::param_type;
    return random_number(mt, param_type{ a, b });
}

std::vector<int> generateRandomNumbers(
    std::size_t size,
    int const lower,
    int const upper)
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(size);
    while (size--)
        v.push_back(random_integer(lower, upper));
    return v;
}

void load_new_random_values(
    std::vector<int>& v,  // lvalue reference to (non-const) vector of int
    int const lower,
    int const upper)
{
    for (auto& value : v)
        value = random_integer(lower, upper);
}

void put_vector(
    std::ostream& ost, 
    std::vector<int> const& v)  // lvalue reference to const vector of int
{
    ost.put('[');
    if (!v.empty())
    {
        ost << v[0];
        for (std::size_t i{ 1 }; i < v.size(); ++i)
            ost << ',' << v[i];
    }
    ost.put(']');
}

int main()
{
    auto v{ generateRandomNumbers(16, -3, 3) };
    put_vector(std::cout, v);
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    load_new_random_values(v, 1, 6);
    put_vector(std::cout, v);
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp

Output
First run: 
[0,-2,3,-1,2,0,3,0,0,2,-2,-3,1,-2,3,-2]

[3,5,4,6,3,2,6,5,4,2,1,2,2,2,5,4]

Second run: 
[-2,-1,-2,-3,2,-2,-1,3,3,-1,3,-1,-2,0,2,-2]

[5,2,3,1,1,4,2,2,6,4,1,6,6,2,1,6]


I think the best way to create an array in the runtime is use the dynamic array
    int* arr = new int[n];

but personally I would use a container which much more dynamic like vector and give the size of the needed random numbers as an argument to the function
void generateRandomNumbers(int lower, int upper, int size, vector<int> &randVec) {

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     randVec.push_back(lower + (rand() % upper));
  }
}



int main() {
  srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

  std::vector<int> vect;
  generateRandomNumbers(1, 20, 5, vect);

  for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) {

    cout << vect[i] << " ";
  }
}




it wasnt OPs question, but the code has some issues that should be addressed. The function does not generate numbers from [lower,upper) as the name of the parameters suggest,  and calling the function too frequent will result in non-random results. Last but not least, your "best way" leaks.
